# Android 2.3.7 Webview won't accept stringified json (result is always an empty object)

Tags: javascript, android, json, webview

No exception, nothing. Tried everything to parse returned stringified JSON by javascript interface in a webview to an object but doesn't work in a Android 2.3.7 webview only.

The returned string is simple: "{test:true}". I have used two methods:

```
oResult = window.app.getDemoObj(); // This function is a java function and resturns the string

alert( typeof oResult ); // Shows that is it a string
    alert( oResult ); // shows the content
    if( typeof oResult === 'string' )
     { 
       // Tried both methods but result is always odd object            
       if( window.JSON )
        { oResult = JSON.parse(oResult); }
       else 
        { oResult = (new Function('return '+(new String(oResult))+';'))(); }
       alert( oResult.test ); // shows undefined, the object is empty with both methods
     }
```

When I replace the line `window.app.getDemoObj()` with `"{test:true}"` it works flawless with both methods. It seems it's a security/origin issue/setting?

How can I get it to work like in other Android versions?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may be encountering is that you need to stringify and not parse the JSON.

To convert JSON objects to text use `JSON.stringify`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

To convert text to JSON objects, use `JSON.parse`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Like I said in the question, result is always an empty object. When calling  window.app.getDemoObj(); this should be a string but is an object. Stringify this and the result is... an empty object "{}". In other higher versions it returns an string and not an object.